# Neural networks applied to micro satellites missions

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit, spacecraft, atmosphere

I'm really interested in micro satellites, but I'm a beginner. So, for the year-end project of a course called "Neural networks" at University I want to do something related with this. I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything that blows my mind and that is not too difficult (for example, all things about deep learning and forecasting are awesome, but I don't have so much time to do something like this.). So, I thought that maybe I could make an atmospheric density predictor, and make a nice drag force predictor (as you know, the atmospheric density is the non-linear term in the drag force), but I read that micro satellites don't care about the drag force because they last so less time in space (like 3 years) that it's not so important. As you know, micro satellites work in LEO, where the drag force is significant. What do you think?

Does anyone have any other idea? I really want to enter in the aerospace "world".

Thanks!

PS: does micro satellites use any propulsion system? How do they move between orbits? If they can't move by themselves, maybe my idea of predicting the drag force is useless